# Is there a way to apply the floyd Warshall to a graph containing OR and AND nodes in order to get the shortest path between vertices

Tags: graph, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I created an oriented dependency graph of semantique web service where nodes are web services and there is an edge between two services if they can be composed(the output of one are similares to the input of the other). the weight is a function depending on Quality of service and similarity

When I get a service request that need a composition of many services, I need the find the shortest path to get the response>

so given the user request (inputs and outputs), I can find the starts and end nodes in my graph and then find the best shortest paths between them using floyd (already precomputed to save time)

this is why i need to get the shortest path between every pair of service in my graph

suppose a service A have the inputs x and y 
x is provided by the output of service B and C 
y is provided by the output of service D

so I will have the relation in my graph :

(B or C)and D --> A

So I am looking for a solution to transform my graph in a way we could apply floyd warshall

Comment: I don't see how to use Floyd-Warshall for that. Also, your graph should be pretty sparse, so no big gain from using it. Modifying Dijkstra for 'and' nodes seems more promising to me.

Comment: What do you mean by  Modifying Dijkstra for 'and' nodes?

Comment: You'd have a special class of nodes that have a tentative distance composed of 2 (or more) parts. They'd only be considered reachable after all parts have a value.